# app.local variable not accessible in ejs scripts

Tags: node.js, ejs

I want to be able to set global variables after the user has logged in, and reference them in any scripts that are part of the app. The reason for doing this is to avoid lots of pages passing the same values around.

My index.js starts like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use("/static", express.static('./views/pages/'));

app.locals.uaccId = "";         // These are my globals
app.locals.uaccName = "";
app.locals.uaccOrgId = "";
app.locals.uaccOrgName = "";
app.locals.uaccEmail= "";

app.use(session({
   secret: 'secret',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

After successful login (using database), I set some values in `request.session`, and these are used to set the `app.locals` values (I thought I could just reference `request` in the EJS pages, but I found I couldn't):

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
   console.log ( '/auth' );
   let lgn = require( "./mods/auth.js");
   lgn.login(request, response);    // Sets values in request.session
   app.locals.uaccId =       request.session.uaccId,
   app.locals.uaccName =   request.session.uaccName,
   app.locals.uaccOrgId =    request.session.uaccOrgId,
   app.locals.uaccOrgName =  request.session.uaccOrgName;
   app.locals.uaccEmail =  request.session.uaccEmail;
});
```

Now when I render any page, I want some user details display in the page header, so in my ejs files I have:

```
<header>
  <%- include('../partials/header'); %>
</header>
```

Then the header.ejs has:

```
      <div class='toplink'> <%= uaccName.replace(/ .*/, '') %>  </div>
      <div class='toplink'> @ <%= uaccOrgName %>      </div>
```

But when I run this I get:

```
TypeError: /u01/WorkSpace/node/views/pages/index.ejs:10
    8| 
    9| <header>
 >> 10|   <%- include('../partials/header'); %>
    11| </header>
    12| 
    13| <div class='centerBox'>

/u01/WorkSpace/node/views/partials/header.ejs:6

 >> 6|       <div class='toplink'> <%= uaccName.replace(/ .*/, '') %>  </div>
    7|       <div class='toplink'> @ <%= uaccOrgName %>      </div>

Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't click with me that the following code is not just executed at startup - it will get executed each time a route is requested.

I added the following right after the `app.use(bodyParser.json());` line above, and then it started working.

```
app.use(function(request, response, next){
   response.locals.uaccId       = "";
   response.locals.uaccName     = "";
   response.locals.uaccOrgId    = "";
   response.locals.uaccOrgName  = "";
   response.locals.uaccEmail    = "";
   if (request.session.uaccId)      response.locals.uaccId       =  request.session.uaccId;      
   if (request.session.uaccName)    response.locals.uaccName     =  request.session.uaccName;    
   if (request.session.uaccOrgId)   response.locals.uaccOrgId    =  request.session.uaccOrgId;   
   if (request.session.uaccOrgName) response.locals.uaccOrgName  =  request.session.uaccOrgName; 
   if (request.session.uaccEmail)   response.locals.uaccEmail    =  request.session.uaccEmail;   
   next();      
})
```